# JS Graph recursive vs iterative DFS order difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, depth-first-search

I looked up iterative Graph DFS and it showed using a stack for the edges but this is producing a different order vs recursive DFS. I tried using a queue for the iterative DFS as well but the only way I could get the same order as recursive DFS was using a stack of Map iterators come back to and resume the iteration over edges, but I feel like there is probably a better way to do it.

I've included each DFS method, recursive, iterative stack, iterative queue, and iterative Map iterators with the order of each being logged:

```
const airports = "PHX BKK OKC JFK LAX MEX EZE HEL LOS LAP LIM".split(" ");

const routes = [
  ["PHX", "LAX"],
  ["PHX", "JFK"],
  ["JFK", "LYC"],
  ["JFK", "OKC"],
  ["JFK", "HEL"],
  ["JFK", "LOS"],
  ["MEX", "LAX"],
  ["MEX", "BKK"],
  ["MEX", "LIM"],
  ["MEX", "EZE"],
  ["LIM", "BKK"],
];

/**
 * Represents a Node (vertex / point) in a Graph and stores it's connections to
 * other Nodes (edges).
 */
class Node {
  /**
   * Constructs a new node with the given data.
   * @param {NodeData} data
   * @returns {Node} This new node.
   */
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.edges = new Map();
  }

  addEdge(node) {
    this.edges.set(node.data, node);
    return this.edges.size;
  }

  getEdges() {
    return this.edges;
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor(edgeDirection = Graph.UNDIRECTED) {
    this.nodes = new Map();
    this.edgeDirection = edgeDirection;
  }

  addVertex(data) {
    if (this.nodes.has(data)) {
      return this.nodes.get(data);
    }
    const vertex = new Node(data);
    this.nodes.set(data, vertex);
    return vertex;
  }

  addEdge(source, destination) {
    const sourceNode = this.addVertex(source);
    const destinationNode = this.addVertex(destination);

    sourceNode.addEdge(destinationNode);

    if (this.edgeDirection === Graph.UNDIRECTED) {
      destinationNode.addEdge(sourceNode);
    }
    return [sourceNode, destinationNode];
  }

  addEdges(edges) {
    edges.forEach(([source, destination]) => this.addEdge(source, destination));
    return this;
  }

  // recursive
  toArrDFS(start, currNode = this.nodes.get(start), visited = new Set()) {
    if (!currNode) {
      return [...visited];
    }

    visited.add(currNode.data);

    for (const edge of currNode.getEdges().values()) {
      if (!visited.has(edge.data)) {
        this.toArrDFS(start, edge, visited);
      }
    }
    return [...visited];
  }

  // Iterative stack - not same order recursive DFS
  toArrIterativeDFS(start) {
    const startNode = this.nodes.get(start);

    if (!startNode) {
      return [];
    }

    const stack = [startNode];
    const visited = new Set();

    while (stack.length) {
      const currNode = stack.pop();
      visited.add(currNode.data);

      for (const edge of currNode.getEdges().values()) {
        if (!visited.has(edge.data)) {
          stack.push(edge);
        }
      }
    }
    return [...visited];
  }

  // Iterative queue - not same order recursive DFS
  toArrIterativeDFS2(start) {
    const startNode = this.nodes.get(start);

    if (!startNode) {
      return [];
    }

    const queue = new Set([startNode]);
    const visited = new Set();

    while (queue.size) {
      const currNode = queue.values().next().value;

      if (!currNode) {
        continue;
      }

      queue.delete(currNode); // O(1) dequeue.
      visited.add(currNode.data);

      for (const edge of currNode.getEdges().values()) {
        if (!visited.has(edge.data)) {
          queue.add(edge);
        }
      }
    }
    return [...visited];
  }

  // Stack of Map iterators - Same order recursive DFS
  toArrIterativeDFS3(start) {
    const startNode = this.nodes.get(start);

    if (!startNode) {
      return [];
    }

    const iteratorsStack = [startNode.getEdges().values()];
    const visited = new Set([startNode.data]);

    while (iteratorsStack.length) {
      const currIter = iteratorsStack.pop();
      const nxt = currIter.next();

      if (!nxt.done) {
        const node = nxt.value;
        iteratorsStack.push(currIter);
        !visited.has(node.data) &&
          iteratorsStack.push(node.getEdges().values());

        visited.add(node.data);
      }
    }
    return [...visited];
  }

  print() {
    let str = [...this.nodes.values()]
      .map(
        (node) => `${node.data} => ${[...node.getEdges().keys()].join(", ")}`
      )
      .join("\n");

    str = `${"_".repeat(100)}\n${str}\n${"_".repeat(100)}`;
    console.log(str);
    return str;
  }
}

Graph.UNDIRECTED = Symbol("directed graph"); // one-way edges
Graph.DIRECTED = Symbol("undirected graph"); // two-way edges

const flightPaths = new Graph().addEdges(routes);
flightPaths.print();
console.log("recursive DFS", flightPaths.toArrDFS("HEL"));
console.log("iterative DFS Stack", flightPaths.toArrIterativeDFS("HEL")); // not same order as recursive
console.log("iterative DFS Queue", flightPaths.toArrIterativeDFS2("HEL")); // not same order as recursive
console.log(
  "iterative DFS stack of Map Iterators",
  flightPaths.toArrIterativeDFS3("HEL")
); // same  order as recursive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack of map iterators has the same result order as the recursive version because it accurately represents the state of the `for` loop in the recursive function.

To contrast your simple stack version, look at the order in which edges are processed after all of them have been pushed onto to the stack: the next iteration takes the top one, which was pushed last; then the second-to-last and so on, essentially processing the edges in reverse order.

If you want to reproduce the same result as the recursive version, you have to stack the neighbors of each node in reverse. Also you'll want to skip processing them again if they have been visited in the meantime (i.e. if they had been put on the stack multiple times).

```
toArrIterativeDFS(start) {
  const stack = [];
  const visited = new Set();
  const startNode = this.nodes.get(start);
  if (startNode) {
    stack.push(startNode);
  }

  while (stack.length) {
    const currNode = stack.pop();
    if (!visited.has(currNode.data)) {
      visited.add(currNode.data);

      stack.push(...Array.from(currNode.getEdges().values()).reverse());
    }
  }
  return Array.from(visited);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like that adds a lot of additional loops over edges vs the stack of iterators ver., can you think of a good reason to do it this way instead of the stack of iterators way?

Comment: It should only loop once over each edge. Sure, the max stack height will be larger than when storing iterators/using recursion, but you cannot really avoid that if you only want to store nodes on the stack.

Comment: (Notice I left out some potential for optimisation, using `stack.push(...currNode.getEdges().filter(n => !visited.has(n)).reverse());` to avoid pushing nodes onto the stack that are already known to have been visited, but it doesn't make much of a difference regarding the general approach)

Comment: Doesn't the loop of `.filter` cancel out the benefit since it is looping over the visited ones?

It's not many extra loops, you're right, but seems like two extra at minimum, convert iter to array, reverse array, spread into `.push`. The Map of edges has no `.slice` so I think you'd need:  `stack.push(...[...currNode.getEdges().values()].reverse());`

Comment: @NeilM Yes, the only benefit is less space required for the stack. It does exactly the same number of loops with or without the filter. And right, I missed that `edges` is a map